# Adding a Pandas df column that concatenates matching values from another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe that concatenates that values from another dataframe that match a certain condition.

If I have dataframes Inventory and Products as inputs:

```
Inventory

Category    All_SKU
Apple       NaN
Banana      NaN
Oranges     NaN


Products

Product       Category     SKU
Macintosh     Apple        4123
Gala          Apple        4356
Navel         Oranges      5897
Cara Cara     Oranges      5324
Red Delicious Apple        4896
Cavendish     Banana       7895
```

I want the output to be

```
Inventory

Category    All_SKU
Apple       4123; 4356; 4896
Oranges     5897; 5324
Banana      7895
```

I've tried this (and other approaches) but get a key error. Not sure if this is the best approach or if there is a better way to tackle this.

```
for row in Products.index:
  InvRow=Inventory.index[Inventory['Category'] == Products['Category',row]]
  Inventory['All_SKU',InvRow]=Inventory['All_SKU',InvRow] + "; "+  Products['SKU',row]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
Inventory['All_SKU']=( Inventory['Category']
                       .map(products[products['Category'].isin(Inventory['Category'])]
                       .groupby('Category')['SKU']
                       .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))) )
print(Inventory)
```

---

```
  Category         All_SKU
0    Apple  4123,4356,4896
1   Banana            7895
2  Oranges       5897,5324
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that should do it

`Products.groupby('Category').SKU.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(list(str(i) for i in list(x))))`

[image]

However if i were you i would use a list rather than a string

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using group by like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Macintosh', 'Apple', '4123'], ['Gala', 'Apple', '4356'], ['Navel', 'Oranges', '5897'], ['Cara Cara', 'Oranges', '5324'], ['Red Delicious', 'Apple', '4896'], ['Cavendish', 'Banana', '7895']], columns=('Product', 'Category', 'SKU'))
result = df.groupby("Category")["SKU"].apply(list).str.join(";")
```

if you want to limit the result to categories in inventory data table you can use merge like below

```py
df_inventory.merge(df, on="Category")
```

Comment: Really helpful to learn about groupby! (as I'm learning Python, I'm finding one of the hardest parts is just finding out what has already been turned into existing functions).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler to understand solution for somebody like myself who doesn't get lambda and other cool 1 line solutions.

```
for d in Inventory['Category'].index:
    cat= data['Category'][d]
    data = Products.query(f"Category == '{cat}'", inplace = False) 
    t = data['SKU']
    Inventory['All_SKU'][d] = t.tolist()
```

(I stored them as list rather than ';' separated string.)

Comment: This is really helpful! Definitely the way I think about programming at the moment. Though also trying to learn the "pythonic" way of doing things

Comment: Yeah. I guess the reason I stick to this style is that I started programming by c++. Good luck with your learning journey.